# Android Exception while returning JSONArray

Tags: android, arrays, json, exception

I am writing an Android app that is querying data from a database through an API written in PHP.
It receives the results as a JSONArray.

For whatever reason, The app keeps crashing when trying to return the JSONArray:

```
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            Log.e("STORES: ", readWSDet());
            JSONArray WSDet = new JSONArray(readWSDet());
            Log.e("POST: ", WSDet.toString());
            return WSDet;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.exception = e;
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("ERROR:" , this.exception.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Both "Log" calls give proper output in the form of

```
[{"id":"0","stop":"18:00:00","price":"99.95","start":"08:00:00","description":"some description","name":"Test","day":"2014-05-04","availability":"9"}]
```

The same code is working fine in other Activities within my project :(

In debug mode, I can see the app processing all steps and when it comes to the return, it jumps into the catch clause. Unfortunately, I just don't manage to get the exceptions cause in the logs.

Any hint on how I could detect what's going wrong ?

Thanks a lot in advance!

P.S. please forgive any issues with formatting or if information should be missing, this is my first question here ;)

EDIT 1:

Logcat for the activity from creation until crash:

```
04-04 07:33:20.633: D/dalvikvm(2015): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 378K, 9% free 4827K/5272K, paused 80ms, total 92ms
04-04 07:33:21.273: W/Bundle(2015): Key dbid expected String but value was a java.lang.Long.  The default value <null> was returned.
04-04 07:33:21.493: W/Bundle(2015): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
04-04 07:33:21.493: W/Bundle(2015): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
04-04 07:33:21.493: W/Bundle(2015):     at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1121)
04-04 07:33:21.493: W/Bundle(2015):     at com.application.jmgmobile.WorkshopdetailsActivity.onCreate(WorkshopdetailsActivity.java:149)
04-04 07:33:21.493: W/Bundle(2015):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-04 07:33:21.493: W/Bundle(2015):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-04 07:33:21.493: W/Bundle(2015):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-04 07:33:21.493: W/Bundle(2015):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-04 07:33:21.493: W/Bundle(2015):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-04 07:33:21.493: W/Bundle(2015):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-04 07:33:21.493: W/Bundle(2015):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-04 07:33:21.493: W/Bundle(2015):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-04 07:33:21.493: W/Bundle(2015):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-04 07:33:21.493: W/Bundle(2015):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 07:33:21.493: W/Bundle(2015):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-04 07:33:21.493: W/Bundle(2015):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-04 07:33:21.493: W/Bundle(2015):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-04 07:33:21.493: W/Bundle(2015):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 07:33:22.213: E/STORES:(2015): [{"id":"0","stop":"18:00:00","price":"99.95","start":"08:00:00","description":"some description","name":"Test","day":"2014-05-04","availability":"9"}]
04-04 07:33:32.933: E/POST:(2015): [{"id":"0","stop":"18:00:00","price":"99.95","start":"08:00:00","description":"some description","name":"Test","day":"2014-05-04","availability":"9"}]
04-04 07:33:32.943: I/System.out(2015): loaded dataset
04-04 07:33:32.983: W/ResourceType(2015): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
04-04 07:33:35.813: D/AndroidRuntime(2015): Shutting down VM
04-04 07:33:35.813: W/dalvikvm(2015): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb1aceba8)
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015): Process: com.application.jmgmobile, PID: 2015
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.application.jmgmobile/com.application.jmgmobile.WorkshopdetailsActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1123)
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:698)
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at com.application.jmgmobile.WorkshopdetailsActivity.onCreate(WorkshopdetailsActivity.java:178)
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-04 07:33:36.043: E/AndroidRuntime(2015):     ... 11 more
```

Edit 2:

Entire Code of the java file:

```
package com.application.jmgmobile;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.EditText;
import org.apache.http.*;

import com.google.analytics.tracking.android.EasyTracker;


class ParseWorkshopdetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONArray> implements Serializable{
    JSONArray ergeniss1 = null;
    private Exception exception;
    private String username= "";
    private String security_token= "";
    private String security_key= "";
    private String security= "";
    private String dbid= "";

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "JMGMobileSettings";
    public ParseWorkshopdetails( Context c )
    {
    SharedPreferences settings = c.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    this.username = settings.getString("username", "none");
    this.dbid=settings.getString("dbid", "");
    this.security_token = settings.getString("security_token", "");
    this.security_key = settings.getString("security_key", "none");
    this.security = security_token + ":" + security_key;

    }



    public String readWSDet(){

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("HERE_GOES_MY_URL");
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("dbid", dbid));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(security.getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }

        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(content));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(ParseWorkshopdetails.class.toString(), "Failed to download data");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         //System.out.println(builder.toString());

        return builder.toString();
    }

    private void creatListOfStores() {

        //String readAgentString = readAgents();
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(readWSDet());
            Log.i(ParseWorkshopdetails.class.getName(),
                    "Number of entries " + jsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Log.i(ParseWorkshopdetails.class.getName(), jsonObject.getString("name"));

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    protected JSONArray doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            Log.e("STORES: ", readWSDet());
            JSONArray WSDet = new JSONArray(readWSDet());
            Log.e("POST: ", WSDet.toString());
            return WSDet;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            this.exception = e;
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("ERROR:" , this.exception.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray objekt) {
        // TODO: check this.exception
        this.ergeniss1 = objekt;

    }

public JSONArray getErgeniss() {
    return ergeniss1;
}
```

}

Comment: what error u got in catch

Comment: please send yours log cat

Comment: @ Jitesh: I added the logcat to the initial post @ Bhanu: This is execatly wat I'm trying to find out ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be the **price** field. In your JSON everything are String, but I think that in your class you have this field as long, so make `Long.parseLong()` when you read this value.

Comment: well, looks like I've been tricket by the place the issue _seemed_ to have occured... indeed, after removing all the pieces of code that try to put values into text fields, the crash is gone. I'll start from here again. Thanks for these quick replies!!!